# How can I cast Google.Protobuf.Collections to ICollection<IFormFile> when upload multiple file with GRPC client

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c#

**I want to upload multiple files with grpc, but I cannot cast the request model to type ICollection<IFormFile**>

**`This is my datamodel`**

```
public class MediaFileUploadDetailDataModel
    {
        public string EntityId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Gets or sets the map entity.</summary>
        public string MapEntity { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Gets or sets the media file type.</summary>
        public Guid MediaFileTypeId { get; set; }

        //public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public bool ImpersonationEnabled { get; set; }

        public ICollection<IFormFile> RequestFiles { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
     }
```

**This is my protofile for grpc client**

```
   service MediaFileManagement
   {
     rpc UploadMediaFile (stream UploadMediaFileRequest) returns(UploadMediaFileReply);
   }

   message UploadMediaFileMessage
   {
    bytes File = 1;
   }

   message UploadMediaFileRequest
   {
  
    string EntityId = 1;
    string MapEntity = 2;
    string MediaFileTypeId = 3;
    bool ImpersonationEnabled = 4;
    string UserId = 5;
    repeated UploadMediaFileMessage RequestFiles = 6;
   }

   message UploadMediaFileReply
   {
    repeated MediaFileMessage SuccessUploads = 1;
   }
```

**And this is my cast operations**

```
 public static MediaFileUploadDetailDataModel ToDataModelForMediaFile(UploadMediaFileRequest model)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                return new MediaFileUploadDetailDataModel
                {
                    EntityId = model.EntityId,
                    MapEntity = model.MapEntity,
                    MediaFileTypeId = new Guid(model.MediaFileTypeId),
                    ImpersonationEnabled = model.ImpersonationEnabled,
                    UserId = new Guid(model.UserId),
                    RequestFiles = model.RequestFiles // this is not working

                };

                return null;
            }
        }
```

**How can I cast GRPC repeated request model to ICollection<IFormFile> ? How to fix this issue?**